# Send data using USB-PD on android phones [ROOT]

Tags: android, usb-c, usb-pd

USB-PD can transfer data at low speeds between devices and is quite a bit simpler than normal USB communication.

Is it possible for an android app to send arbitrary USB-PD data? The phone has root access.

I am designing a USB-PD power bank and i want it to be able to report its battery level, wear level and charge speeds to the phone using an app. The normal way would be to use USB but that would require a more complex circuit and USBC connector.

What i am trying is to instead send everything using USB-PD itself and somehow android would report these values to the app.